# Using input inside facets on composite components

Tags: jsf-2

I am using a composite component in my application that declares and renders a facet section inside a tab view:

```
<composite:facet name="ambienteEspecifico" required="true"/>
...
<p:tabView value="#{cc.attrs.gerenciador.entries}" var="servidor">
   <p:tab title="#{servidor.key}">
    <composite:renderFacet name="ambienteEspecifico"/>
   </p:tab>
</p:tabView>...
```

The problem is when I am using the component, if I put any input tag like:

```
<f:facet name="ambienteEspecifico">
   <h:inputText value="#{servidor.value.espaco}"/>
</f:facet>
```

The server returns a "Target Unreachable, identifier 'servidor' resolved to null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException". If I change to an output tag:

```
<f:facet name="ambienteEspecifico">
   <p:outputLabel value="#{servidor.value.espaco}" />
</f:facet>
```

The value is correctly displayed without any exception being thrown. So it seems that the problem is related only to input components. If I put the input tag in the component side:

```
<p:tabView value="#{cc.attrs.gerenciador.entries}" var="servidor">
   <p:tab title="#{servidor.key}">
    <composite:renderFacet name="ambienteEspecifico"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{servidor.value.espaco}"/>
   </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

It also works without any exception being thrown. Am I dealing with a bug?
By the way, I am using `jsf 2.2.2.`

Thanks!

Comment: Unlike Outputs, Inputs require a non-null object to operate on. Somehow, servidor is null when it reaches amienteEspecifico.

Comment: What is strange is that even throwing an exception the input shows the default value of server.value.espaco. I tried setting it to 5 on the constructor and the value 5 is shown in the input.

Comment: I don't think server is null because the output shows the real value of server.value.espaco. What is strange is even in the input the value 5 is shown but the application throws the PropertyNotFound exception.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening then. Is it an option for you to use <composite:insertChildren/> instead? I know that one works because it doesn't care what you put in, it will just insert it as is into the composite before creating it into the component tree.

Comment: I had already tested the code with insertChildren and it worked, bu I couldn't use insertChildren because I had more than one tag that I had to insert in different places of my composite component. Finally I had no other choice but change my code to support insertChildren.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ali C, using `<composite:insertChildren/>` solved the problem.

```
<p:tabView value="#{cc.attrs.gerenciador.entries}" var="servidor">
  <p:tab title="#{servidor.key}">
    <composite:insertChildren/>
  </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

It works as a workround, at least to me. The only problem is that sometimes you have to render more than one child on different places of the composite.